# jquery get json items

Tags: jquery, getjson

my data.json looks like this:

```
{
    "selection_form" : {
        "entities" : { 
            "name":"0002" ,
            "name":"0103" ,
            "name":"0104" ,
            "name":"0122" ,
....
```

this script looks loke this

```
  <script>     
            $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {   
                $.each(data.selection_form.entities, function(i,item){
                    $("#enity").append('<p>'+data.selection_form.entities.name+'</p>');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

i want to get all names wraped in a p tag like

```
<p>0002</p><p>0103</p>....
```

but the result is ony the last name item. I can't find a soloution for that. Need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object can't have properties with same names. `entities` object has one `name` property with value of `0122`.  You should change the property names.

```
{
    "selection_form": {
        "entities": {
            "name1": "0002",
            "name2": "0103",
            "name3": "0104",
            "name4": "0122",
        }
    }
}

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {   
      $.each(data.selection_form.entities, function(i,item){
           $("#enity").append('<p>'+item+'</p>');
      });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vB6qe/

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the JSON property names. Instead of having a JSON object there, it makes more sense to have an array:

```
{
    "selection_form" : {
        "entities" : [ "0002" , "0103" , "0104" , "0122" ]
    }
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {   
        $.each(data.selection_form.entities, function(i,name){
            $("#enity").append('<p>'+name+'</p>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aPp9w/1/) of iterating that structure.